# size-incompatible Dense layer after Flatten in keras in Convolutional models for word embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network in order to classify a set of news in 3 categories. The idea is to gather all news corpus in blocks of max 10 news per minute, each news being given by a max number of words of 30; so each sample should be composed by a tensor of dimensions (sample, 10, 30). 
This is the input to an embedding operation, that outputs a tensor of size (sample, 10, 30, 200) where 200 is the embedding dimension for each word.

than I pass this embedded input to a convolutional operation, I flatten it and then pass it to a Dense layer for the final outputs (3 labels). The model is as follows:

```
news_inputs = Input(shape=(n_news_per_min, n_words_per_news, ), name='news_per_min')
news_inputs_embeddings = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                                   output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                                   input_length=n_words_per_news,                                   
                                   weights = [embedding_weights],
                                   trainable=False)(news_inputs)
conv = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(news_inputs_embeddings)
flat = Flatten()(conv)
dense = Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(flat)
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=news_inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

a deeper look at the objects created gives the following:

```
news_inputs:
<tf.Tensor 'news_per_min_9:0' shape=(?, 10, 30) dtype=float32>

news_inputs_embeddings:
<tf.Tensor 'embedding_10/Gather:0' shape=(?, 10, 30, 200) dtype=float32>

conv:
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_11/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 10, 30, 32) dtype=float32>

flat:
<tf.Tensor 'flatten_5/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>

dense:
<tf.Tensor 'dense_11/Relu:0' shape=(?, 16) dtype=float32>

out:
<tf.Tensor 'dense_12/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 3) dtype=float32>
```

the model summary is as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
news_per_min (InputLayer)    (None, 10, 30)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_12 (Embedding)     (None, 30, 200)           87766800  
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 32)            57632     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)          (None, 960)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 16)                15376     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 87,839,859
Trainable params: 73,059
Non-trainable params: 87,766,800
```

all things seem to work fine when I compile it, but both fitting or predicting yields this error:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16)
InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [16,9600], In[1]: [960,16]
     [[Node: dense_15/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](flatten_7/Reshape, dense_15/kernel/read)]]
     [[Node: loss_7/mul/_157 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_693_loss_7/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'dense_15/MatMul', defined at:
```

It seems like the first Dense layer ('Dense_15') is not able to connect to the flattened convoluted layer but I am stuck understanding why.

Also, trying to add a MaxPooling Layer after the convolution one yields an error (I am not including it here but it says `"IndexError: tuple index out of range"` so I guess something is wrong with the dimension of the conv layer.
Any help please?

Comment: I can't spot anything obviously wrong. If you are still curious, please provide a way to reproduce the error.